# Finding $E(X \mid X>Y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are IID continuous random variables. I am confused to find $E(X \mid  X>Y)$

I know that $$E[X \mid Y=y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{f(x, y)}{f_{Y}(y)} d x$$

But i am not sure what is the definition of  $E(X \mid  X>Y)$

I just need some input to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be computed as follows. Note that by the law of total expectation,

$$\begin{align}E[X{\bf1}_{X>Y}]&=E[E[X{\bf1}_{X>Y}|{\bf1}_{X>Y}]]\\
&=E[X{\bf1}_{X>Y}|{\bf1}_{X>Y}=1]P({\bf1}_{X>Y}=1)+E[X{\bf1}_{X>Y}|{\bf1}_{X>Y}=0]P({\bf1}_{X>Y}=0)\\
&=E[X|X>Y]P(X>Y)\\
\implies E[X|X>Y]&=\frac{E[X{\bf1}_{X>Y}]}{P(X>Y)},
\end{align}$$

where $$\begin{align}E[X{\bf1}_{X>Y}]&=\int_\Omega x f(x,y)dxdy,\\
P(X>Y)&=\int_\Omega  f(x,y)dxdy,\\
\Omega&:={\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x>y\}}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I am not sure what do u mean by $\mathbb{X} \mathbf{1}_{X>Y}$, Is it indicator function multiplied with random variable $X$?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Correct, it is a product of $X$ and a Bernoulli random variable

Comment: In the second step, you are applying law of total probability. Is it applicable to expectation also?

Comment: @Umeshshankar No I'm applying the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)